# undeclared crate or module inside `if cfg!(test)` even if defined in dev-dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-cargo

Here is the error:

```
let tmp = tempdir::TempDir::new("cargo_test").expect("failed to create tempdir");
          ^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `tempdir`
```

My cargo.toml looks like this:

```ini
#...
[dev-dependencies]
tempdir = "0.3.7
```

And in the code:

```rust
let path = if cfg!(test) {
            let tmp = tempdir::TempDir::new("cargo_test").expect("failed to create tempdir");
            tmp.path().to_str().map(|x| x.to_string()).unwrap_or(path)
        } else {
            path
        };
```

I do not understand why it fails, when i run `cargo test`. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`cfg!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.cfg.html) macro evaluates to a constant `true` or `false` depending on the contents, so on non-test builds it evaluates to

```rust
let path = if false {
    let tmp = tempdir::TempDir::new("cargo_test").expect("failed to create tempdir");
    tmp.path().to_str().map(|x| x.to_string()).unwrap_or(path)
} else {
    path
};
```

which still has the dependency in it, and will type check everything and so it sees the missing crate.
Instead you have to remove the whole first block from compilation:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
let path = {
    let tmp = tempdir::TempDir::new("cargo_test").expect("failed to create tempdir");
    tmp.path().to_str().map(|x| x.to_string()).unwrap_or(path)
};
```

Comment: In case you need an `else` branch (which you don't need here), you can use `#[cfg(not(test))]`

Comment: @SvenMarnach it is exactly what i did, after reading  the answer! Thanks!

Comment: There is also [`cfg_if`](https://docs.rs/cfg-if/latest/cfg_if/) if your 'conditions' are more complex.